# The function 'ta.rsi' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, consistency

I don't quite understand what is wrong with this warning...

line 105: The function 'ta.crossover' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 91: The function 'ta.rsi' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 92: The function 'ta.sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 92: The function 'ta.stoch' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 93: The function 'ta.sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 94: The function 'ta.crossover' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 97: The function 'ta.sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

line 98: The function 'ta.stdev' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

This is the section I am having the warning with:

if haClose>haOpen and outema > outsma

```
lookbackInput = input.int(50, "Lookback in bars", minval = 1, maxval = 4999)

smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1, group="STOCH RSI")
```

smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1, group="STOCH RSI")

lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1, group="STOCH RSI")

lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1, group="STOCH RSI")

for i = 0 to lookbackInput by 1

```
    rsi1 = ta.rsi(close\[i\], lengthRSI)        //line 91 warning

    k = ta.sma (ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)

    d = ta.sma (k, smoothD)

    if ta.crossover (k, d) and (d \< Lowerline)
```

break
for j = 0 to 10 by 1

```
            basis := ta.sma(close\[j\], lengthBB)

            dev := mult \* ta.stdev(close\[j\], lengthBB)

            lower := basis - dev
```

haClose := (open[j] + high[j] + low[j]  + close[j]) / 4
haOpen := float(na)

haOpen := na(haOpen[j+1]) ? (open[j] + close[j] ) / 2 : (nz(haOpen[j+1]) + nz(haClose[j+1])) / 2

```
            haHigh := math.max(high\[j\], math.max(haOpen, haClose))
```

haLow  := math.min(low[j],  math.min(haOpen, haClose))

```
            if ta.crossover (haLow, lower)
```

LONG := true      // line 105 warning

plotshape(Long, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.green)

I just don't quite understand the warning and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

The history of series variables used inside Pine functions is created through each successive call to the function.

When you have this function call in a local scope, you are breaking the historical consistency of that series variable. Please see [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks).

To solve that issue, you can execute those functions in global scope.